# Ubuntu ISO customized image

Tags: system-installation

i have a very curious and yet it may turn out to be very fuuny question for others in this forum ..

So here is the situation :

we have preseed script(this might eb customized as well)  for ubuntu installation and also have post installation script which has various softwares embedded into that image .

My question is how does that installer knows about the script ?
and what is the process to create a iso image which will give us the desired installation as it was intended to design ?

Am completely new to OS plaftorm.
Currently we install ubuntu from USB sticks ?
So if someone can help how this installation process is going forward will be very much  helpful?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to [read the documentation on preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html), and how to [remaster an ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) to add the preseed file or extra packages.

As for "how does the installer know about the script", you can choose how you feed the installer the preseed file, section [B.2.1. Loading the preconfiguration file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html#preseed-loading) in the first link.

Comment: Hi  karel .Thanks for your reply.I will go through the above mentioned links .